# Gnuplot: operations with data in different blocks

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file consisting of two blocks (separated by a single blank line) and would like to plot the difference between data from block 1 and block 2, i.e., something like

```
 plot 'a.dat' using 1:($2_1-$2_2)
```

where `$2_1` is supposed to mean "data from block 1, col.2" and `$2_2` "data from block 2, col.2". Is that possible within Gnuplot, and if so, how?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

This task is most likely not possible directly in Gnuplot, however, one can preprocess the data file first, using, e.g., gawk and then plot the modified file. For example:

```
dataFile="a.dat"
plotCmd(fname)=sprintf("<gawk '\
    BEGIN{mode=0;l=0;} \
    mode==0{if(NF==0){mode=1;}else{x[NR]=$1;y[NR]=$2;}} \
    mode==1{if(NF>0){mode=2;l=NR;}} \
    mode==2{print $1,y[NR-l+1],$2}' %s", fname)

plot plotCmd(dataFile) u 1:($2-$3) w l
```

The gawk script reads the file and saves the first and second column into arrays `x` and `y` until it reaches a blank line (zero number of fields). Then it skips all consecutive blank lines until it reaches a non-empty line (`NF>0`). It remembers the position of this line in the input file and then outputs for each line in the second block the x-coordinate together with the corresponding y-coordinate from the first block, i.e., a data file such as

```
1   2
2   4
3   6



1   4
2   8
3   12
```

would be transformed into

```
1   2   4
2   4   8
3   6   12
```

This assumes that the x-coordinates in both blocks match...